# Is there ambiguity in the way "reference" is used?

Tags: php, reference, terminology

For example, in PHP we can write something like this:

```
class C {
    var $x;

    function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->x;
    }
}

function f1($obj) {
    $obj->x = 2;
}

$a = new C(1);
f1($a);
echo $a; // 2
```

And some would say that this indicates objects are passed by reference, because you can modify their properties and those changes are reflected outside of the class. i.e., the object is not copied the way primitives are.

But then we can write this:

```
function f2($obj) {
    $obj = new C(2);
}


$b = new C(1);
f2($b);
echo $b; // 1
```

Which now suggests the object is not passed by reference at all. In reality, the object is copied (i.e., passed by value) but not *deep*-copied; `$obj` is copied, but `$x` still refers to the same thing.

I've heard the word "reference" used to mean both ways; some would say PHP is pass by reference, others would say pass by value.

If we say that PHP is pass by reference, then what do we mean when say define a function like

```
function f3(&$obj)
```

? *That* function takes a reference an to an object, this suggests the first meaning is wrong.

But then what about languages like C++, and structs in C#? My C++ is a bit rusty, but I believe the whole class actually gets deep-copied when pass it around, which is why it's encouraged to make your functions take references if possible, or use pointers. In C# there's a difference between structs and classes in how they get passed.

What do you call this deep-copying behaviour, if not pass by value?

It seems we have 3 behaviours and only two phrases to describe them, and this is creating a lot of confusion in the community.

Heck, I'm just waiting for one of you to tell me I wrote something wrong here.

---

In summary, the 3 behaviours are:

1. Objects are deep-copied (the object and its properties are cloned)
2. Only the object is copied (its properties still refer to the same chunk of memory)
3. The object is not copied at all

Technically, what should we call each of these behaviours? pass-by-???

Comment: Someday (or probably not), PHP will implement a `const` keyword for arguments, and this will remove any ambiguity whatsoever... :)

Answer (score 2):

First things first: You might want to read [***References Explained***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

---

Normally, variables are always passed by value. What matters is what the value actually is.

If the variable "holds an object", it holds a *reference to the object*.

Thus, when you have a function definition like

```
function foo($bar) {}
```

a *reference to the object* is passed. That is why you can change the object.

But if you assign a new value to the variable inside the function, then you are just overwriting the reference with something else and you loose the reference to the object.

So assuming you have a variable `$someVar` that you pass to the function, `$bar` and `$someVar` will have the same value (namely a reference), but they have their own location in memory.

Before:

```
$someVar -> object_reference  ┐

                              ├ -> object

$bar     -> object_reference  ┘
```

After:

```
$someVar -> object_reference  -> object



$bar     -> other_value
```

---

Now, if the function definition is like

```
function foo(&$bar) {}
```

then you are actually passed a *reference to the location in memory of some other variable*.

If you call the function with `foo($someVar)`, `$bar` will point to the same location as `$someVar`, i.e. if you assign a new value, you are overwriting that particular location in the memory.

Before:

```
$someVar  ┐

          ├ ->  object_reference -> object

$bar      ┘
```

After:

```
$someVar  ┐

          ├ ->  other_value         object

$bar      ┘
```

Comment: So... to answer the question then. You're saying, what? Objects are passed by *reference to the object*, and in the other case, you're passing a *reference to the location in memory*? And what about primitives? Or deep-copied objects? You've used the word "reference" in both your scenarios, so you'd agree then, that there's ambiguity unless fully qualified?

Comment: @Mark: Imo the term is not ambiguous. It is correct to use the term in both situations because they describe the same concept. You'd never say that a function accepts a reference if the parameter is not defined with the `&` symbol. And you know that if you pass objects around, you can modify their properties. Note that in your second example, you are not operating on the properties of the passed object, but you are assigning a new value to the variable. A reference is just something that uniquely defines something else. You will find the same behaviour in other OO languages.

Comment: @Mark: Sorry if I cannot explain it in a more understandable way.

Comment: No, I think I understand what you mean. "Reference" is being used consistently in that sense, but then the phrase "pass by reference" isn't. It could mean... oh forget it. I understand what goes on behind the scenes, it's just silly wording. I think we should call the ampersand case an "alias" though.

Answer (score 1):

If I had my druthers, the term "object reference" in .net would be replaced by something like "object-id", to make clear that in most cases when an object is passed to a routine, the object-id is passed by value (though there are some cases, like Dictionary.TryGetValue, where an object-id is passed by reference).  Using the same term to describe an object-id and a type of parameter passing leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the first two are both called pass-by-value. How deep a deep copy occurs depends on the copy semantics of the class in question, which can and should be specified by the programmer (some classes are handles to resources and must be shallow-copied; others, such as most containers, must be deep-copied). Python has library functions for deep and shallow copying. Deep copying is sometimes called cloning, esp. in C++ and Java.

The third is called pass by reference. This is the general term for passing something that can be modified in-place by the callee.

(C is an exception to this convention, since it has no notion of reference, but pass-by-pointer is almost the same as pass-by-reference.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to differentiate... references to variables and references to objects. As long as you don't assign an other value to the parameter $obj, you are dealing with the exact same object as outside of the function. After assigning an other object to it, the variable has changed but since you only passed a reference to the object and not one to the variable, the variable on the outside is still untouched pointing to your original object...